# How to use custom theme in iccube reporting v6?

Tags: theming, iccube-reporting

In iccube reporting V5x, I was able to load a custom theme by adding the following instruction in `ic3report-config.js`

```
ic3RegisterTheme('Pkcs', 'theme/', 'PkcsTheme.js' , 'PkcsTheme.css' );
```

then inside `pkcstheme.js`,  I used

```
var ic3;
(function(a) {
    a.Themes.registerTheme({
        name: "PKCS",
        cssCls: "pkcs-theme",
        boxHeaderCls: "pkcs-header",
        reportContainerDefaultStyle: "pkcs",
        amChartsDefaultStyle: "Pkcs Main",
etc...
```

But, in V6, `a.Themes.registerTheme` does not exist...

What is the proper way to do this now ?

Comment: Not yet done, in progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IcCube v6.1 introduced new custom theme management:

### Run-time

Now it is possible to load/change theme in a run-time with a Public Reporting Context API:

[Demonstration report](http://demo6.iccube.com/icCube/doc/ic3report?name=%2Fshared%2FTheme%20Definition&ic3demo)

Javascript snippet executed with "Change colors" button:

```
function(context, item) {
    if(!window.demotheme){
        window.demotheme = _.cloneDeep(window.ic3ThemeElegant);
    }

    demotheme.id = "ic3-demotheme";
    demotheme.name = "Demo";

    demotheme.vars.palette = ["#374649", "#fd625e", "#f2c80f", "#01b8aa", "#79c75b", "#8ad4eb"];
    demotheme.vars.backgroundColor = "#eaeaea";
    demotheme.vars.borderColor = "#eaeaea";


    // adding variable to a theme
    demotheme.vars.boxBackgroundColor = "white";


    context.setTheme(demotheme);
}
```

### Preload

IcCube Theme manager will register any theme that is placed in global JavaScript scope that starts with ic3Theme (e.g `window.ic3ThemeElegant`) and it will be available in "Report Settings" as an option.

For example you can use such code in a ic3report-local.js:

```
$script(options.rootLocal + 'ic3ThemeWhiteBox.js', function(){
      options.callback && options.callback();                                                  
   })
```

Content of ic3ThemeWhiteBox.js is:

```
window.ic3ThemeWhiteBox = {
            "id": "ic3-white-box",
            "name": "White Box",
            //... theme definition ...
    })
```